# If GoogleJsonResponseException: then skip and move to next row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-sheets-api

I have a working script. need to improvise to have no manual interruption. We have multiple Profiles in Analytics, sometimes we lose access and sometimes we have. So when i run the Script, If we lost access to 1 of 60 profiles, i have to delete that entry manually then rerun the script.
What i want is, If there is below error, Then skip and continue with next row

"GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to analytics.data.ga.get failed with error: User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile."

```js
function GoogleAnalytics() {
 
  var doc2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dashboard = doc2.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  for(var i=52;i<65;i++){ 
  var viewId = dashboard.getRange(i,13).getValue(); // Your Google Analytics view ID
 
  
        
  var metric = 'ga:metric, ga:metric2, ga:metric3';
  var option = {'segment': 'gaid::-5'};
  
       
   var result = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(viewId, metric, option);


    var metric = result.totalsForAllResults['ga:metric'];
    var metric2 = result.totalsForAllResults['ga:metric2'];
    var metric3 = result.totalsForAllResults['ga:metric3'];
  
        var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Current document
        var sheet = doc.getActiveSheet(); // Current sheet
  
    sheet.getRange(i,14,1,1).setValue(metric); 
    sheet.getRange(i,15,1,1).setValue(metric2); 
    sheet.getRange(i,16,1,1).setValue(metric3); 
} }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it this way:

```
function GoogleAnalytics() {
  var doc2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = doc2.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  var sheet = doc2.getActiveSheet(); // Current sheet
  const vs = sh.getRange(52, 13, 13).getValues();
  var metric = 'ga:metric, ga:metric2, ga:metric3';
  var option = { 'segment': 'gaid::-5' };
  for (var i = 0; i < vs.length; i++) {
    var viewId = vs[i][0]; // Your Google Analytics view ID
    try {
      var result = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(viewId, metric, option);
    }
    catch(e){
      continue;
    }
    if (result) {
      sheet.getRange(i + 52, 14, 1, 3).setValues([[result.totalsForAllResults['ga:metric'], result.totalsForAllResults['ga:metric2'], result.totalsForAllResults['ga:metric3']]]);
    }
  }
}
```

Without the benefit of working data some of this may not be correct but using setValues  and getValues should speed it up considerably and the try catch blocks should help with not getting result consistently.  Also you want to avoid making unnecessary declarations in loops.

Answer (score 1):

I might understand the question incorrectly (if so, please clarify) but it sounds to me like you just need to add...

```js
function GoogleAnalytics() {
 
  var doc2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dashboard = doc2.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  for(var i=52;i<65;i++){ 
  try { //...this line and...
  var viewId = dashboard.getRange(i,13).getValue(); // Your Google Analytics view ID
 
  
        
  var metric = 'ga:metric, ga:metric2, ga:metric3';
  var option = {'segment': 'gaid::-5'};
  
       
   var result = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(viewId, metric, option);


    var metric = result.totalsForAllResults['ga:metric'];
    var metric2 = result.totalsForAllResults['ga:metric2'];
    var metric3 = result.totalsForAllResults['ga:metric3'];
  
        var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Current document
        var sheet = doc.getActiveSheet(); // Current sheet
  
    sheet.getRange(i,14,1,1).setValue(metric); 
    sheet.getRange(i,15,1,1).setValue(metric2); 
    sheet.getRange(i,16,1,1).setValue(metric3); 
  } catch(e) { //...this part
    console.log(e); //optional, catch(e){} is perfectly valid as well, or any code you might want to execute on error
  }
} }
```